# Async method that is returning bool

Tags: c#

I have an Async method in C# that is calling SQL function which is returning true or false and method is returning bool variable that is true or false.

This is my method:

```
    public async Task<bool> Canlog(string userName, string pass
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        bool queryResult = false;

        using (context )
        {
            using (context .Database.Connection)
            {
                context .Database.Connection.Open();

                string sqlStatment = .....

                queryResult = authorizationContext.Database
                        .SqlQuery<bool>(sqlStatment)
                        .Single();
            }
        }

        return await queryResult;
    }
```

when I try this, I am getting error in this line return await queryResult that cannot await bool.

Comment: `queryResult` is just a `bool` variable. There is nothing async there. And I also can't see any entity framework there...

Comment: @thefiloe framework  is not the main concern here so I simplify the code. It is calling the function and return true or false. I need this as a async method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Single()` returns `<T>`, not `Task<T>`.  What you want is `SingleAsync()`:

```
    return await authorizationContext.Database
                                     .SqlQuery<bool>(sqlStatement)
                                     .SingleAsync();
```

Also, you can't have your await outside of your using statements because then your DB context will be disposed before the async operation is compelte.